# Any recommended Solaris 10 (for Apache & MySQL app) load balancer?

Tags: solaris, load-balancing

Any recommended Solaris 10 (for Apache & MySQL app) load balancer to intro?

HAProxy is nice but i dun think its support MySQL (only for HTTP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful here, the question is confused.

HTTP is one protocol, and handled by one very common type of load balancers. There are very many answers on load balancing already, browse around for info.

MySQL uses a different, and state-full protocol between client and server. As such, MySQL **must not** be load balanced by simple IP load balancing, or you'll see some very weird bugs.

For MySQL you could use [MySQL Proxy](http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/MySQL_Proxy), connection pooling middleware, and other solutions -- since I'm no MySQL expert I will not try to answer this in more depth.

Comment: Thanks for clarify the difference.

Would it possible to use HAProxy for both HTTP and MySQL?

Comment: No, it would not.

Answer (score 1):

Solaris probably isn't the best OS to run a load balancer on.  You want the focus to be on speed with an LB, but speed isn't Solaris' forte (unless you're on big iron, and you probably aren't).

If you want something cheap, look at Coyote Point.  If you want something "Enterprise", look at F5.  Otherwise, setup a small Linux box, and look at all the various load balancers available for Linux.

Answer (score 0):

what kind of load balancing do you want to do with mysql?  If it is read only why bother make several slave installs and have them each sync from the master server(s) some set(one or more) of your web servers hit each slave and have app level failover if a db server dies.  If you are doing writing to the db I do not think mysql is there yet, it is in the product but people I know are not using it.

Comment: let say i looking for a solution on scale a big and heavy database. any suggestion beside mysql?